Total number of paths
A person starts at the origin  (0, 0) on the  xy -plane and must move to the point  (n, 0) . The rules for movement are:

The person can move:

Diagonally up (like ( / )): ( (x, y) to (x+1, y+1) ),
Diagonally down (like ( \)): ( (x, y) to (x+1, y-1) ), or
Horizontally forward (like ( - )): ( (x, y) to (x+1, y) ).


The person cannot move below the  x -axis at any point.

The person must end exactly at (n, 0) , ensuring the upward and downward movements balance.


My approach:- I tried finding a recurrence relation by reframing the question as finding the total number of sequences of -1,0 and 1s such that at any instant the sum of numbers of the sequence in consideration along with the previous terms of the sequence is always positive or 0 and the total sum of the sequence should be 0. Let total ways be A_n. The first number should be 0 or 1 and if we start with 0, the second number should be 0 or 1 again which corresponds to A_n-1. If the first number is 1 and the second -1, then the number of ways will be A_n-2 for this kind of sequences. But I was not able to find any relation for the sequences starting with 1 and second number be 0 or 1. Also tried some combinatorics (integral equation and rearrangements) but didn't get anything fruitful.

Please use MathJax.

What you are describing is a Motzkin path and the number of such paths is known as Motzkin number. There’s a bunch of literature on this topic. See this for example: https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/download/v22i2p8/pdf/

@spectralmath Thanks, didn't know this problem was already thoroughly discussed.

Suppose you were only able to move diagonally. Then these are Dyck paths, are only possible if $n$ is even, and the number of them is the Catalan number $C_{n/2}=\frac{1}{1+n/2}\binom{n}{n/2}$.
Now suppose you use precisely $k$ horizontal movements. Then we need $n-k$ even, and we can do this by taking any Dyck path of length $n-k$ and inserting $k$ horizontal movements anywhere, so there are $C_{(n-k)/2}\binom nk$ possibilities.
Therefore the total number of paths is $$\sum_{k\equiv n\pmod 2}C_{(n-k)/2}\binom nk.$$

What comes up, must come down :-)
So every step up must be accompanied by a step down, which drives me to the following formula:
$$\sum_{i=0}^{i=\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor} {n \choose {2i}}$$
(I was writing this as an answer, but now I realise this gives the possibility to go down first, which is not allowed. Sorry, but I'll leave it in case somebody has an improvement.)
